# CodeDom - XML flag into some common sense

Tags: .net, interop, codedom, dll

if i review the .csproj of my Test solution i see a flag as follows:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="Interop.Encore">
<HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\\Interop.Encore.dll</HintPath>
**<EmbedInteropTypes>False</EmbedInteropTypes>**
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.Core" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
<Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
<Reference Include="System.Data" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

My question si i need to set the EmbedInteropTypes to false within the CodeDom project before it generates a .DLL on it's own. (dll that holds non EmbedInteropType dll's)

Anyone have a solution ?

I'm looking at

```
_CurrentCodeFile.AssemblyCustomAttributes.Add(
   new CodeAttributeDeclaration("EmbedInteropTypes", new CodeAttributeArgument[] { new 
      CodeAttributeArgument(
         new CodePrimitiveExpression(false))}));
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you misunderstand what assembly attributes are. They are usually placed in `AssemblyInfo.cs` and look like `[assembly:AssemblyCultureAttribute("de")]`. And there is no `EmbedInteropTypes` attribute that I could find.

Now, based on my tests with referencing COM assemblies using CodeDOM, you don't need to do anything special if you don't want to embed the interop assembly, just reference it.

On the other hand, if you did want to embed it, you would need to explicitly use [the `/link` command line option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264728.aspx), by setting [`CompilerOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.compileroptions.aspx).

Comment: Secondly, using the /link command DOES NOT give you the flag to disable (not provide) or other forms by means of linking the file... afaik. i could be wrong - we can have drinks about it sometime when im in thailand again...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about, but I certainly won't go the 8000 km to Thailand just to have drinks with you :-)